# How can I use a where clause and check if a string variable contains in a many table column

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have made an method that will check if name value contains in the name column on current table, but I also need to see if the name contains in another column that is in a many table(TABLE.Project).

`TABLE.Customer 1 --- *(many) TABLE.Project(Which have column named "Name")`

This is the method:

```
Public List<SearchObject> Finditem(string name)
{
    var query = from o in db.tbl_Custommer
                where o.Name.Contains(name)
                select new SearchObject
                {
                    Url = o.tbl_Webs.WebUrlName,
                    Name = o.Name,
                };
    return query.ToList();
}
```

Do I need to iterate throught each `o.Project`?

Any kind of help is appreciated alot!

Comment: So you have a relationship many to many from Customer to Project and you want to check the Project.Name column and return the corresponding Customers?

Comment: @xanatos I have one(Customer) to many(Project) and I want to check if my string parameter contains in Project.Name and return the SearchObject with corresponding values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

presuming you have the relationship correctly setup and its called Projects then you could use any - i.e. return customers where the name matches name and they have at least one project with the name also matching:

```
var query = from o in db.tbl_Custommer
                   where o.Name.Contains(name) && o.Projects.Any(p => p.Name.Contains(name))
                   select new SearchObject
                   {
                       Url = o.tbl_Webs.WebUrlName,
                       Name = o.Name,
                   };
```